# Conversion JSON string to date in android

Tags: android

I am getting a JSON `"dt_txt":"2017-07-26 21:00:00"` as date and time but I only want date in format of "dd MMM, yyyy" i.e "26 Jul, 2017".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SimpleDateFormat

```
String dt_txt = "2017-07-26 21:00:00";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = fmt.parse(dt_txt);

        SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String newFormat = fmtOut.format(date);

        Log.i("kapil", " " + newFormat);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, also can you give same for time? I think I should use the time too.

Comment: @Alishahmomin updated the code for time as well